# Exhaustive list of recreational mathematical concepts

Tags: recreational-mathematics, big-list

There are many simple yet elegant, addictive and entertaining mathematical concepts. For example, drinker paradox, pigeon hole principle, Monty Hall problem, Hilbert's paradox of the Grand Hotel, etc.
Can somebody please provide me with a list of such recreational mathematical concepts?

Comment: This is a pretty good start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Recreational_mathematics

Comment: @MatthewConroy I want to read more about principles and paradoxes than problems.

Comment: You're welcome! That page has links to many Wikipedia pages, including pages on principles and paradoxes.  Wikipedia is very interconnected, so, for instance, from the page on the Homicidal chauffeur problem, you will see links to Variational Calculus. For paradoxes, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Paradoxes Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Poke around some of [this stuff](http://anduin.eldar.org/~problemi/singmast/) by [David Singmaster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Singmaster). I doubt you'll find more exhaustive lists on the internet, at least at present.